# CMD - Rename Local Computer, Join Domain, Join Specific OU

Tags: domain, windows-command-prompt, wmi, active-directory

Alright so not sure if this is entirely possible all in one.

Situation: Brand new computer not on the domain, just a local workgroup. Want to change that computers name, join a domain, and put the computer name in a specific workgroup for that domain. This can all be done via the GUI all at once so it should be hypothetically possible via command line right?

I can rename a local computer using this method: CMD > `WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM where "Name='%computername%'" CALL Rename NEWNAME, Password, User`

This works however it requires a restart for the changes to happen.

Next I made a batch file that works great to do what I want using NETDOM, however it can't be used until that computer is restarted due to the name change...

```
SET /P compname=[promptString]
SET /P org=[promptString]

NETDOM JOIN %compname% /Domain:DOMAIN.NET /OU:%org%,DC=DOMAIN,DC=net /UserD:DOMAIN\user /PasswordD:password /Reboot:15 /verbose
PAUSE
```

So I guess my question is... is there any way to do this in one way without having to restart? If a restart is absolutely required its too much time consumption; the only reason I want to do this VS using the windows GUI is to get it in the OU I want right away without having to pre-stage or go into AD and move the computer.

Comment: Joining an Active Directory domain *requires* a restart. You can stage a new computer object in the OU in which it belongs, but there's no getting around a reboot at least once.

Comment: What happens if you change the second command to use the %newname% instead of %computername% (after the rename of course, but no restart)?

Comment: jscott - I realize this however through the GUI you can do both of these at the same time which is why I was assuming it would be possible to do it through cmd, wish netdom could rename the computer and join the domain all at the same time.

Comment: uSlackr - the second command that uses %compname% is just a variable for a user-input computer name that my batch file prompts to put in.  If you put in the newcomputer name that was just named from the first command it does not recognize it as NETDOM is not doing the domain join locally but from the domain controller which that server does not recognize the new computer name until it restarts after doing the first command.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps split the operation into two scripts. Run the second one automatically after the reboot using a [RunOnce](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314866/EN-US) key. The first script could automate the setting up of the second.

Comment: Yeah I've also considered this however the point of the whole thing is to do it as a one-time thing as the GUI does; rename, join the computer all in one and then restart, not restarting in-between.  Real point is to make it take less time to rename, join the domain, and put the computer in the proper OU.  If having to wait for a restart it would be faster to use the GUI and then connect to AD and move the computer to the proper spot =\

Answer (score 0):

If you set a timeout for the NETDOM command, then can you set a timeout which is ridiculously long enough for the script to also rename computer before the reboot happens? In other words, instead of having a `PAUSE` command after `NETDOM JOIN`, just put in the `WMIC` command after that. (Or does that smell too much like a race condition?)

Comment: Not sure how this would work, if you do netdom first then rename w/ rmic you would join under the old name not the new name you are renaming it to and that old name would be the one that is put into the correct OU in AD instead of the new one =\

Comment: hmmm, good point. does execution of the WMIC command automatically and instantly reboot computer? or is there a flag to prevent that? (I'm sorry if all I'm asking are obvious questions right now, but I'm hoping that even dialoging might help you troubleshoot it).

Comment: No it does not automatically restart.

Comment: So... Run the WMIC command, and then run NETDOM? both in the same script. Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately no, netdom connects to the DC who looks for the computer to connect to in order to perform such tasks.  If you try to do netdom without restarting it can't find the computer's name since you JUST created it and haven't restarted yet so the computer doesn't actually have the new name but is still technically running under the old name.